# How to use lambda in template definition in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

Here's a trivial example of what I'm trying to achieve. Is it even possible to pass lambda into template function?

**HEADER FILE**

```
class my_impl {
public:
    template<typename F> void do_something(F && f);
};
```

**CPP FILE**

```
// .cpp file
template<typename F> my_impl::do_something(F && f)
{
    // ... implementation
}

template void my_impl::do_something<std::string &&>(std::string &&); // OK
template void my_impl::do_something<???>(???); // what goes here for lambda?

// used like this
my_impl impl;
impl.do_something( "123" );
impl.do_something( []() { 
   ...
} );
```

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) You can already use it, what you're looking for is how to explicitly instantiate this template.

Comment: The `// OK` and `// what goes here for lambda` lines are not required at all in your sample code.  Delete them and your code compiles.  Please be more clear why you think you need them.

Comment: @Yakk note that these are in .cpp file.

Comment: Did you try copy-pasting your sample code above, deleting those two lines, and compilimg?  Again, *you still do not need those lines*.  I get that there are "nearby" problems where you might need those lines, but post actual code that actually has problems.  Before submitting, take your code back to a compiler and make sure it still has the property you want.  Pseudo code is useless here.

Comment: @Ragnar: You want to write specialization for a lambda ?!

Answer (score 0):

A lambda is an instance of unique, compiler-generated, internal type.

You can see this for yourself by using your debugger. For example, given the following short snippet of test code:

```
class my_impl {
public:
    template<typename F> void do_something(F && f);
};

template<typename F> void my_impl::do_something(F && f)
{
}

int main()
{
    my_impl m;

    m.do_something( []() {} );
}
```

With gcc 5.3, stepping through the debugger, the following results are observed:

```
main () at t.C:22
22      m.do_something( []() {} );
(gdb) s
my_impl::do_something<main()::<lambda()> >(<unknown type in /tmp/t, CU 0x0, DIE 0x23e>) (this=0x7fffffffe44d, f=<unknown type in /tmp/t, CU 0x0, DIE 0x23e>)
    at t.C:9
```

Note that gdb reports the template instance as type `my_impl::do_something<main()::<lambda()> >`. The compiler generated an internal fake type of `main()::<lambda()>` for the lambda type. Of course, you cannot refer to a type like that.

I do not see a way of refer to a lambda's internal type.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the lambda depends on the lambda itself. 
You can do

```
 auto l=[] (/*arguments*/) {/*body*/};
 template void my_impl::do_something<decltype(l)>(decltype(l)&&);
```

However this will work only with the lambda `l` because the compiler generates new type for each lambda.

It can be used like

```
my_impl impl;
impl.do_something(l);
```

Comment: This works for trivial lamba. But I need to capture class member fields and some local variables and these change depending on usage.